# In C++, should iterable types be non-polymorphic?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

### A bit of background:

I am currently working on an assignment from my OOP course which consists in designing and implementing a phone book manager around various design patterns.

In my project there are 3 classes around which all the action happens:

- `PhoneBook`;
- `Contact`        (the types stored in the phone book);
- `ContactField`   (fields stored in the `Contact`).

`ContactManager` must provide a way to iterate over its contacts in 2 modes: unfiltered and filtered based on a predicate; `Contact` must provide a way to iterate over its fields.

### How I initially decided to implement:

All design patterns books I came across recommend coding to an interface so my first thought was to extract an interface from each of the above classes and then make them implement it.

Now I also have to create some kind of polymorphic iterator for things to be smooth so I adapted the [Java iterator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to write forward iterators.

### The problems:

- The major setback with this design is that I lose interoperability
  with stl `<algorithm>` and the syntactic sugar offered by range
  based for loops.
- Another issue I came across is the `Iterator<T>::remove()` function. If
  I want an iterator that can alter the sequence it iterates over
  (remove elements) then all is fine however if I don't want
  that behavior I'm not exactly sure what to do.

  I see that in Java    one can throw `UnsupportedOperationException`
  which isn't that bad    since (correct me if I'm wrong) if an
  exception isn't handled then    the application is terminated and a
  stack trace is shown. In C++ you    don't really have that luxury
  (unless you run with a debugger    attached I think) and to be honest
  I'd rather prefer to catch such    errors at compile time.

---

The easiest way out (that I see) of this mess is to avoid using interfaces on the iterable types in order to accommodate my own stl compatible iterators. This will increase coupling however I'm not sure it will actually have any impact in the long run (not in the sense that this project will become throw away code soon of course). My guess is that it won't however, I'd like to hear the elders opinion as well before I proceed with my design.

Comment: I read `ContactManager` and stopped reading at this point. Good Luck.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Could you please elaborate on what's wrong with it? Perhaps I have misused the terminology here.

Comment: Maybe you should name it PhoneBook instead of something manager, when it's a phone book.

Comment: Java only had one kind of polymorphism -- dynamic polymorphism with virtual functions.  C++ has that, but also static polymorphism with templates, which is more useful in this instance.  You might want to read http://www.catonmat.net/blog/cpp-polymorphism/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably take a slightly different approach.

Firstly, iteration over a contact is pretty simple since it's a single type of iteration and you can just provide `begin` and `end` methods to allow iteration over the underlying fields.

For the iteration over a `PhoneBook` I would *still* just provide a normal `begin` and `end`, and then provide a `for_each_if` function that you use to iterate over only the contacts that are interesting, instead of trying to provide a super-custom iterator that skips over un-interesting elements.